# regular expression to get the start and end matches of a string

Tags: regex, flutter, dart

i Have a string of words. I want get a word which   begins and ends with  3 back ticks ```` ``` ````. how to I use regular expressions to accomplish this in flutter. I have tried this```` (^```.*\.```$)\w+ ````but its not working on a sentence like ```` Hello there, ```friend```, how are you doing? ````

Comment: You could use a capturing group \```(\w+)```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern you tried ```` (^```.*\.```$)\w+ ```` uses anchors to assert the start `^` and the end `$` of the string and in between match any char except a newline followed by a literal dot around triple backticks.

After that it tries to match 1+ word characters which will not match.

You could use a capturing group and match 1+ word characters in between

````
```(\w+)```
````

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vQlAyU/1)